# How to launch Bluefy browser from a React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, web, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I need to launch a webpage from my React native app on iOS in Bluefy browser. (The page will communicate to a Bluetooth peripheral device.)
The Bluefy browser cannot be set as default browser in iOS.

Does anyone know how to launch it using custom url scheme with Linking?

The only thing I need to know is the url scheme for Bluefy.

Comment: I contacted them using a contact from on PNNsoft website.  The "Contact us" link in the app itself is disabled ( grayed out). Waiting for their response.

Comment: Interesting. For me that in-app “contact us” option composes an email for bluefy.support@pnnsoft.com.

Comment: PNN soft responded!
The custom scheme is      bluefy://open?url=example.com 
A R-N code would look like:
>>>>
 const url = 'bluefy://open?url=example.com';
 Linking.openURL(url);
>>>>
Put it in your answer , I'll accept it.

Comment: I’m happy to do so, but I’m not sure I deserve the credit for that. Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But kind of you to offer…

Comment: Its okay. I don't really care for stack overflow ratings ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to 34n, PNN Soft reports that the scheme is `bluefy://open?url=example.com`.

E.g.,

```js
const url = 'bluefy://open?url=example.com';
Linking.openURL(url);
```